# Combining two VBA bits of code

Tags: excel, vba

I have to bits of code that do what I want.  The first bit, creates new worksheets based on a master tab and populates data from it.  The second finds the last line of data and adds a sum formula at the first empty cell in columns L through AJ.  I've been trying to combine them so it runs off one macro. So when the new sheets are being populated it also runs the sum formula.  Would appreciate any help.

Creates the new worksheets and populates:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetsFromTemplate()
'Create copies of a template sheet using text on a master sheet in a specific column
'Sheetname strings are corrected using the UDF below
Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP As Worksheet, wasVISIBLE As Boolean
Dim shNAMES As Range, NM As Range, NmSTR As String, NR As Long

With ThisWorkbook                                               'keep focus in this workbook
    Set wsTEMP = .Sheets("Template")                            'sheet to be copied
    wasVISIBLE = (wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible)              'check if it's hidden or not
    If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible      'make it visible

    Set wsMASTER = .Sheets("Master")                            'sheet with names
                                                                'range to find names to be checked
    Set shNAMES = wsMASTER.Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlFormulas)     'or xlFormulas

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                          'speed up macro
    For Each NM In shNAMES                                      'check one name at a time
        NmSTR = FixStringForSheetName(CStr(NM.Text))            'use UDF to create a legal sheetname
        If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & NmSTR & "'!A1)") Then       'if sheet does not exist...
            wsTEMP.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)           '...create it from template
            ActiveSheet.Name = NmSTR                            '...rename it
        End If
        With .Sheets(NmSTR)
            NR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            wsMASTER.Range("B1:B1").Copy
            .Range("A" & NR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
            NM.Resize(, 500).Copy .Range("A" & NR)
        End With

    Next NM

    wsMASTER.Activate                                           'return to the master sheet
    If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetHidden       'hide the template if necessary
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                           'update screen one time at the end
End With

MsgBox "All sheets created"
End Sub


Function FixStringForSheetName(shSTR As String) As String

'replace each forbidden character with something acceptable
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, ":", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "?", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "*", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "/", "-")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "\", "-")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "[", "(")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "]", ")")

'sheet names can only be 31 characters
    FixStringForSheetName = Trim(Left(shSTR, 31))

End Function
```

Adds sum formula to last row:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubUntilLastRow()
Dim CurCal As XlCalculation
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, colsLastRow As Long
Dim cols As Variant, SumCols As Long, colsArray As Variant
Dim biggestRow As Long
Dim shNAMES As Range

With ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    CurCal = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    biggestRow = 1

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("CPB - NAM")

    colsArray = Array("L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ")

    For Each cols In colsArray
    colsLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, cols).End(xlUp).Row
    If colsLastRow > biggestRow Then
    biggestRow = colsLastRow + 1
    End If
    Next cols

    For Each cols In colsArray
    colsLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, cols).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Cells(biggestRow, cols).Formula = "=SUM(" & cols & "9:" & cols & colsLastRow & ")"
    Next cols

    ws.Range("B" & biggestRow).Value = "TOTAL"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = CurCal
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If this works is it not a potentially a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site question?

Answer (score 0):

First you transform your Sub

```
Sub SubUntilLastRow()
```

into a function that takes a sheet as a parameter

```
Function SubUntilLastRow(ws As Worksheet)
```

Delete the following lines of code:

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("CPB - NAM")
```

and in the `For Each NM In shNAMES` loop you put the line at the bottom
    SubUntilLastRow(NM)

to call the function for the coresponding worksheet

Comment: I don't want them to run sequentially as the second sub right now only runs for the sheet thats named.  I want it to run for each worksheet that the first sub makes.